# JQuery ControlID in User control

Tags: jquery

I have an ASP.NET Usercontrol and am using JQuery to do some stuff for me. I use the User control dynamically in different pages. I need to get the ControlID of the control that is in the user control. How do i dynamically do a $('#myControl') instead if $('#HostPage.myControl'), **what is the syntax for $('<%#myControl.ControlID'%>), or can I do this.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
$('#<% = myControl.ClientID %>')
```

`$("[id$='myControl']")` might also work - that'd find you an element with an ID that ends with myControl.

Comment: $('#<% = myControl.ClientID %>')
 is not working. ANy reasons?